# How to iterate through dictionary of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to iterate through this dictionary of dictionary. Ultimately I want to divide up the values from each dict.. e.g., 0.5/0.4, 0.3/0.2, and 0.1/0.1 to find the max, but I haven't reached there yet. Any help with the iteration would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

dict = {('a', 0.5): ('b', 0.4), ('c', 0.3): ("d", 0.2), ('e', 0.1): ('f', 0.1)}

for keys, values in dict:
    print "key: %s" % keys
    print "values: %f" % values
    for keys1, values1 in dict[keys]:
        print "key1: %s" % keys1
        print "values1: %f" % values1
```

However I get an error:

key: a 
values: 0.500000 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 8, in 
    for keys1, values1 in dict[keys]: KeyError: 'a'

Comment: That is not a dictionary of dictionaries, that is a dictionaries where they keys and values are `tuple`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First rename your variable `dict` to `d`.

This is not dictionary of dictionary. This is dictionary containing tuples as key, and values.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    a = k[1]
    b = v[1]
    print(a/b)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple for loop works here:

```
In [1169]: for d in dict_:
      ...:     print(d[-1], '/', dict_[d][-1])
      ...:     
0.5 / 0.4
0.3 / 0.2
0.1 / 0.1
```

Some considerations -

1. Both your keys and values are tuples, so use `[-1]` to index the last element in each case
2. Preferably don't use `dict.items()` because it creates a copy of the dict in memory to iterate over
3. Do not use `dict` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin `dict`

Answer (score 2):

```
dict = {('a', 0.5): ('b', 0.4), ('c', 0.3): ("d", 0.2), ('e', 0.1): ('f', 0.1)}

for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    print "key=", key
    print "value=",value
    print "division=",key[1]/value[1]
```

## Output

```
key= ('a', 0.5)
value= ('b', 0.4)
division= 1.25
key= ('c', 0.3)
value= ('d', 0.2)
division= 1.5
key= ('e', 0.1)
value= ('f', 0.1)
division= 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

to iterate over a Dictionary you need to call the function ״iteritems():״ ( in Python 2.7) you can read more about it here

> [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

```
dicte = {('a', 0.5): ('b', 0.4), ('c', 0.3): ("d", 0.2), ('e', 0.1): ('f', 0.1)}
for keys, values in dicte.iteritems():
    print "key: {}".format(keys)
    print "values: {}".format(values)
    keys1, values1 = keys
    print "key1: {}".format(keys1)
    print "values1: {}".format(values1)
```